# Pyqt5-Problem with emit signal from other module

Tags: python, pyqt5

```python
class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.work = Worker(self)
        self.work.finished.connect(self.ppp)

    def ppp(self):
        print(6)
```

I have no idea what's happening ?
I try to emit the signal from A module then connect function in B module
but the function didn't be called
and there is no error appear

```python
class Worker(QObject):
  # give worker class a finished signal
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.continue_run = True  # provide a bool run condition for the class

    def send(self):
        self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: Sorry but both your question and code are confusing. First of all, `A` is a *class*, not a module. Then, what and where is the "`B` module"? Please [edit] your post and provide a *valid* [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are you trying to emit the signal?  It isn't included in your code.